# How to fix configuration file

Tags: init, ubuntu-18.04

My file /etc/init/myserver.conf used to work on Ubuntu 12.04 using `sudo service myserver start,stop, restart`. I copied it to /etc/init/ on Ubuntu 18.04 and it did not work. How can I fix it?

```
# masterserver - start master server service 

description "Service that starts master.sh"
author "<hadjieff>"

# When to start the service
start on runlevel [2345]

# When to stop the service
stop on runlevel [016]

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn

# Essentially lets upstart know the process will detach itself to the background
expect fork

# Run before process
pre-start script
    # Put bash code here if necessary
end script

# Start the process
script
    cd /home/hadjieff/hadjieff/server
    sudo java -Djava.security.policy=security.policy -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.91  -cp . -jar Registar.jar --xbee=true --test=false
end script
```